# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled not displaying back arrow with custom actionbar view

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Everything is set properly in the manifest when I click the icon it works as expected, however no < arrow is shown on the `ActionBar`. Any ideas?

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bits you're passing into [`ActionBar.setDisplayOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions%28int%29) are telling the `ActionBar` to only show the "home" icon and your custom view. You should also pass in [`ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP). As in:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Alternatively, just call [`ActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled%28boolean%29):

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually turns out I was calling something twice which was causing the issue but this solution works